# Magento - No invoice on Payment method cash (Mindstretch modules)

Tags: magento, payment

we are maintaining a webshop based on Magento which has payment modules installed from Mindstretch. We are using the 'cash on pick-up' option, but the problem is that the module creates an invoice when the order has been send in. However, when 'cash on pick-up' is selected it should not create an invoice. This should only happen when they actually pick it up. So we need to disable the making of the invoice. Problem is that I have no idea where to start looking. Below the config.xml and system.xml files

---

CONFIG.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <Mindstretch_Contant>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mindstretch_Contant>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
                <contant>
                    <class>Mindstretch_Contant_Helper</class>
                </contant>
                <!--
                 <payment>
                    <rewrite>
                    <data>Mindstretch_Contant_Helper_Data</data>
                    </rewrite>
                </payment>
                -->
            </helpers>
        <models>
            <contant>
                <class>Mindstretch_Contant_Model</class>
            </contant>
        </models>
    <adminhtml>       
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mindstretch_Contant>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mindstretch_Backend.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mindstretch_Contant>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

        <resources>
            <contant_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mindstretch_Contant</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </contant_setup>
            <contant_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </contant_write>
            <contant_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </contant_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contant>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mindstretch_Contant</module>
                    <frontName>Contant</frontName>
                </args>
            </contant>
        </routers>
    </frontend>


    <default>
        <payment>
            <contant>

                <active>0</active>
                <model>contant/paymentLogic</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Contant</title>
                <api_key>46</api_key>
                <api_secret>46</api_secret>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </contant>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

---

SYSTEM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>

        <payment>
            <groups>

                <contant translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <label>Contant</label>
                    <sort_order>601</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New order status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>contant/paid</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                         <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>51</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <min_order_total translate="label">
                            <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>98</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </min_order_total>
                        <max_order_total translate="label">
                            <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </max_order_total>
            <sort_order translate="label">
       <label>Sort order</label>
       <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
       <sort_order>999</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      </sort_order>


                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </contant>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

PAYMENTLOGIC.PHP:

```
<?php
class Mindstretch_Contant_Model_PaymentLogic extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Set forced canCreditmemo flag
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Mage_Payment_Model_Observer
     */
    protected $_code                    = 'contant';
    protected $_isGateway               = true;
    protected $_canAuthorize            = true;
    protected $_canCapture              = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial       = false;
    protected $_canRefund               = true;
    protected $_canVoid                 = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = true;
    protected $_canUseCheckout          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = true;
    protected $_canSaveCc               = false;

    /*public function authorize (Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {

    }

    public function capture (Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {

    }

    public function refund (Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {

    }
    */
    public function void (Varien_Object $payment)
    {

    }

}
?>
```

Hope someone can give me some direction of where to look. Thanks

Comment: Based on the config you've posted, the important code is in app/code/local/Mindstretch/Contant/Model/PaymentLogic.php, can you please post the contents of that file?

Comment: Maybe the new order status needs to be "pending"

Comment: @Jonathan ; edited the original post with the Paymentlogic.php file included now.

Comment: There is btw also a file called Paid.php, with this content:

Comment: class Mindstretch_Contant_Model_Paid
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value'=>1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Select')),
            array('value'=>0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invoiced (paid)')),
        );
    }

}